# Can there be 2 fuel pumps in a petrol car?

Tags: nissan, primera, fuel-pump

My car is a Nissan Primera P12 (2500 cc) and recently I heard from my mechanic that there are 2 fuel pumps in the car. One closer to fuel tank, and another closer to the engine.

Is this a normal configuration for a petrol engine? Why would it need 2 pumps instead of just 1 pump like most cars? and what the implications of such configuration? (maintenance, etc.)

Anywhere I can look to confirm this? (website, specs, etc. or how can I confirm this by looking at the car?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I suggested in a comment to your other question, post up pictures of the two pumps and we should be able to help you identify what they are

Comment: cool, working on it. Car is still at the mechanic haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the vehicle has [GDI (Gasoline direct injection)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gasoline_direct_injection) then yes there will be a low pressure or lift pump and a high pressure pump. One run on 12 volt the other run by the engine.

I don't think your vehicle is equipped with GDI but I am not sure. I am not aware of any gasoline production vehicles other than GDI that come equipped with more than one fuel pump.

Comment: Apparently is it Direct Injection http://www.carfolio.com/specifications/models/car/?car=232980